# Call a Vue method from outside the Vue app (Vue Webpack CLI)

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I need to call a method from outside my app. I am using the Vue CLI. My method is in a component and looks something like this:

```
export default { 
  name: 'home',
  ...
  methods: {
    theMethodINeedToCall() {
      // does stuff
    }
  }
```

I have been searching for a way to access `theMethodINeedToCall()`. It's not hard to get there when you're *not* using the Vue CLI, but *with* the CLI, I can't seem to find my way there.

Comment: Where exactly do you need to call it? Like, in a terminal window from Node.js? Or just in another part of your app? Look into using Mixins instead of you want methods elsewhere, functions inside components are really only meant to be used inside the component, although I guess something like MyComponent.methods.theMethodINeedToCall() might work, depending on your setup.

Comment: I'm integrating google recaptcha, which requires a callback function. See https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a mixin to me than a component. Basically a mixin lets you extend the vm with your own functions, so you can create global functions accessible everywhere in your code. I'm a bit too tired to show you how to make a mixin for this but the official vue.js sites have pretty good documentation on this. A function accessible everywhere is basically the definition of a global function, and that's what a mixin lets you create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method has nothing to do with the component it's better you host the method outside of the component

At last component is just an object ,just import the component where yo want and call the method;

```
import MyComponent from './path/'

MyComponent.methods.theMethodINeedToCall();
```